# Binding to an NSDictionary's "allValues" array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

Am I misunderstanding something about bindings? I bind (an NSArrayController's content) to an NSDictionary's "allValues" array, and it thinks it's empty. I bind to a random object with a property that I've set to be that same NSDictionary's "allValues" array, and it works fine.

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong? Furthermore, if this is expected, what is the standard way to deal with this? Making relatively purposeless objects just to hold arrays in properties so I can bind to them seems ugly.

Comment: If the keys are completely irrelevant, should the data be stored primarily in a dictionary?

Comment: The keys are important, just not in this one particular view of the data.

Comment: There are many imaginable situations where keys are totally irrelevant to a view, but completely useful to a controller object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding to `@"allValues"` means the dictionary is sent a `-valueForKey:@"allValues"` message. The dictionary then interprets that by looking up `-objectForKey:@"allValues"` which is not what you are after in this case.

Try binding to `@"@allValues"` instead (see the `-[NSDictionary valueForKey:]` docs for more details)