# Binding an NSArrayController to NSDictionary allValues

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsdictionary, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I've encountered a few scenarios where I'd like to show some entries in an NSDictionary in an NSTableView. (My instincts to user an NSDictionaryController are always foiled by the need to make every object implement copyWithZone, which I find to be an absurd requirement that is fatal to usability...)

Instead, I'm trying to bind an NSArrayController to the allValues property of an NSDictionary, with the intent of binding respective columns of the table various properties of the objects in the array. However, I can't find a correct way to specify this binding within Cocoa, via the Controller Key and Model Key Path properties of the array controller.

When I attempt to bind the array directly to allValues, the array controller's arrangedObjects property is constantly empty - even when objects are added to the dictionary, when the addition is enclosed by [dictionary willChangeValueForKey: @"allValues"] and [dictionary didChangeValueForKey: @"allValues"] calls, even after calling setContent: on the array controller after adding the object.

Of course, I found this Stack Overflow thread:

[Binding to an NSDictionary's "allValues" array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285844/binding-to-an-nsdictionarys-allvalues-array)

...and tried various versions of @"@allValues" in the Model Key Path field, but none produced the desired results.

So here's my question: If I have ArrayControllerOne bound to an object, and I'd like to bind ArrayControllerTwo to the allValues property of an NSDictionary property (called "instances") within ArrayControllerOne.selection, what should I enter in the Controller Key and Model Key Path fields?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to bind to allValues when that dictionary is a selection in another array controller?  I'm having a hard time imagining what you're trying to do. If you could give an example of what kind of data is bound to arrayController1 that would be helpful.

Comment: In my scenario, the dictionary is not "a selection in another array controller." It's just a member of a class instance. That is, I have an object with a member that's a dictionary, and I want to present a table with each column reflecting some information about each *value* in the dictionary. I'd also like to allow users to select a row in the table, and access the dictionary value represented by the row. To accomplish those two tasks, I'd like to create an array controller bound to my_obj.my_dict.allValues, and a table with columns bound to a property of the entries in the array controller.

Answer (score 2):

You must have missed one, because I found that you can bind the content array of an array controller to a dictionary's allValues by using dict.@allValues (no quotes), where dict is the property name of the dictionary. Why this works, I don't know -- I can't find any documentation for this.

BTW, if I add a new key-value pair to the dictionary, I use self.dict = _dict; to get the table view to update.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. When I do this, the array controller's arrangedObjects array contains a single object, irrespective of how many entries are in the dictionary. (I can't even tell what kind of object it is, due to limitations in the Cocoa debugger.) I think that that syntax is not invoking the allValues accessor method and presenting the results in arrangedObjects, but simply assigning the allValues accessor to arrangedObjects.

Comment: That's strange, when I did it, it behaved normally and my table view showed the correct object for each value in the dictionary. Perhaps there's something else wrong in your code -- I did it with just a simple dictionary.

Comment: I'll try it again and will report back. Thanks for your contributions.